# How to solve this system for real $x,y,z$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Find the real values $x,y,z$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
x+y^2+z^3=21\qquad (1)\\
y+z^2+x^3=71\qquad (2)\\
z+x^2+y^3=45\qquad (3)
\end{cases}$$

Thank you everyone. This problem have some nice methods,

my idea
$$(1)-(2),(2)-(3),(1)-(3)$$
But following is very ugly,

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(4,3,2)$.

Comment: @Gerry -- how'd you do that?

Comment: @bubba: Do you think it is easy to solve this problem with hand? Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal,This problem is from china  students

Comment: @math110: In general, it is not easy to solve such systems. Maybe, they were asked to find an integer solution to the system. If you use Maple or Mathematics, they will give you this solution provided by Gerry.

Comment: @bub, first of all, I decided to look for positive integer solutions. There may be lots of other solutions, but I'll let someone else find them. Then from (1), $z\le2$; from (2), $x\le4$; from (3), $y\le3$. So there is nothing more natural than to see whether $(4,3,2)$ works. It does.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson : You don't take into consideration any possible negative integer solutions while I consider these. This makes the difference, isn't so?

Comment: @Gerry -- thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 5):

By substitution $x = -z^3-y^2+21$ we come to the system $$\{z^6+2y^2z^3+y^4+y^3-42z^3-42y^2+z+396=0,$$ $$-z^9-3y^2z^6-3y^4z^3-y^6+63z^6+126y^2z^3+63y^4-1323z^3-1323y^2+z^2+y+9190=0\} $$ in two variables $y,z.$ The necessary and sufficient condition for $z$ to be a root of the reduced system is its resultant in $y$ equals zero. One can read [the theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) or/and consider a simple example  of the system $\{xy-3=0, x+y-4=0\}$ having $y^2-4y+3$ as the resultant in $x$. Computing the resultant of the reduced system in $y$  with help of Maple, we obtain $$z^{27}-189 z^{24}+15869 z^{21}-270 z^{19}-770589 z^{18}-806 z^{17}+ $$ $$2751 z^{16}+23703246 z^{15}+82077 z^{14}-1652484 z^{13}-476609381 z^{12}- $$ $$ 3301322 z^{11}+43400763 z^{10}+6247199406 z^9+64051684 z^8-$$ $$ 614744566 z^7-51522303964 z^6-586660519 z^5+4368480127 z^4+ $$ $$244239132451z^3+2045234869z^2-12927999002z-506350844104 . $$
  Its integer zeros may be only the  divisors of $506350844104=2^3\cdot7^3\cdot{22717}\cdot{8123}$. With help of Maple it is easy to determine that  $z=2$ is the only integer root of the discriminant. Substituting it in the reduced system, we obtain $ \{y^4+y^3-26*y^2+126=0, -y^6+39*y^4-507*y^2+y+2130=0\}$. Let us continue to find integer solutions. Factoring $126=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 7$ and $2130=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot71$ and making substitutions in the last system,
  we find $y=3$ is  its unique  integer root. At last, $x=21-3^2-2^3=4.$ See the same result and other solutions obtained with Maple in  [Maple workshheet](http://rapidshare.com/files/334838450/system.pdf) exported as a PDF file of size 4.7 MB. I think the usage of [Groebner basis methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groebner_basis) to this end is the same, but in other formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I calculated the groebner basis of the given polynomials as @user64494 mentioned. I used Maxima. The groebner basis can be calculated by

```
load(affine)
grobner_basis([x+y^2+z^3-21,y+z^2+x^3-71,z+x^2+y^3-45],[x,y,z]);
```

or by the more performant

```
load(grobner)
poly_reduced_grobner([x+y^2+z^3-21,y+z^2+x^3-71,z+x^2+y^3-45],[x,y,z]);
```

The first method calculates  three polynomials of the following structure

$$ \bar{a} z +\sum_{i=0}^{26}a_i x^i$$
$$ \bar{b} y +\sum_{i=0}^{26}b_i x^i$$
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{27}c_i x^i$$

the last polynomial is a polynomial in $x$ and its greatest common divisor with its derivate is $1$ so the mutiplicity of each of its zeroes is $1$. That gives  27 different roots from the last equation and for each of this $x$ we can calculate exactly one $y$ and exactly one $z$ from the second and first equation. So the system has exactly 27 different solution triples. Only one of the has integer coeffizients. This can be easily verified by checking the factors of the constant term of the third polynomial.
When solving the last polynomial numericaly  all additional zeros were complex.  But I did not estimate the errors of these results so I maybe there are some additional real solutions.

Here is the groebner basis:

```
en
[-22854301286836911302951962008959981349675920830211880722252897899482766960*z+
101241650877485702175357226711705181369414285719323271704900599033*x^26+
730493130445989508228919909546810713843847398313779223651087519824*x^25+
3540573574249015290611751414231595174251438296726560696362459674492*x^24-
57601095861658849483369268199123170716838909838202201760548216991291*x^23-
416669170352980097977678503713070508928161605337142188835441001313348*x^22-
2016456288758571753652652790132907402955549749060394170347444871057144*x^21+
14337131315976690795006215432188627110313244968234681142084635386092125*x^20+
103978480705322953404121328349373353056605692054795541302018434791315640*x^19+
502408404617273090219544471435187577487194272063835221567343328898564742*x^18-
2039034484647452387028658505252719405461628375610422339900185203597626901*x^17-
14826474432634752132622616062227371848884875498083166152593448873803203530*x^16-
71521311114728848896178916165302972594230182479373367878179386134592570525*x^15+
181226940795534346770385260687298983718065667166055108247474393752335913762*x^14+
1321223671539991769014646804675227239824380224814739351302708123497923971045*x^13+
6362363772582616985318251284770118333682888331874189797324777618243837202922*x^12-
10307276445941045849534345820507113099945294311434649206210081411446918484325*x^11-
75343259257336924709387227029071797120852196803269283659418048487065673154552*x^10-
362146215827542847154810112038519093263359021196749346190089147623222093355067*x^9+
366332422580930000531415481752870222410425957605250528460101433785913371958926*x^8+
2684909428447129499237047976674561168601618821874354114035878109413695326368746*x^7+
12879883798773848342540629050370768049664513490474144436583475665514444464655428*x^6-
7438517094093356983768963560448216577725696705790510624875660142169716771602186*x^5-
54664246407870934149414874884315975429538144465899291373677653339786209016391993*x^4-
261677584970079842980777720997231146139739299214259648915820513414255604682118559*x^3+
66066390235017785913904655414260680985998364039917501956028362648150414415329741*x^2+
486824957266269401188349248475110086868907667753511055300723913552755230112968255*x+
2325133789380244519283058674358315974252223598711974898685477942350490058629214164,-
22854301286836911302951962008959981349675920830211880722252897899482766960*y-
21928789092803889010334179574530184728288965460282593414217253279*x^26-
152103310477485971369396850528778398228632402972685478700533993872*x^25-
988179692325307396783678134780425835532168323719473916698506679716*x^24+
12933819405944247941172667124481567911681725018225952498581194464573*x^23+
89938135538433583335922325553012386064779341649646642361591239103724*x^22+
582839561747331703375181095894833526579379002016722929878345498144072*x^21-
3331141319180171470215338707159514382225219185646945703056257598501275*x^20-
23229961710706062880802555954436210242730111880472754898962774770976120*x^19-
150129341853633401912908815913160119483105852726405693279392081337521146*x^18+
489378818781203857880434101561926565990504171151681432414788820341094563*x^17+
3423513056887354008445341032875654979344170277490134585626494166430952070*x^16+
22059528092709636101254096434519805314580702526855170316960293809562972075*x^15-
44857998497083833724275743674521090210369556809354566210855457229866525566*x^14-
314892768405662620941263918560036836148834876514280384278560885299721478835*x^13-
2022455842784927028311019517125865551837537411904715466791190485162918188246*x^12+
2627290904346381452089886122894549612284128981398782728265980522465609711075*x^11+
18511710895421508337181421922431934716807573882378263882516613703456364182136*x^10+
118475634137858317062762823521711571537050276219847738152725178350433229707101*x^9-
96022820398943598967632410768386023063188488168438098386178972900846941634338*x^8-
679275985511615170010158066671976445958836285330040108431256781661535751362758*x^7-
4330693730813796394106212173292340472948499531356086191489896849483786632851484*x^6+
2002348350491636851981453322355110239376545077965342970879612273698559893101318*x^5+
14225370617524898062345035822331501546653752741532711702558265171048399604012159*x^4+
90313914479160605603365299986764796656164484141145941454210585974096513407067177*x^3-
18240391291763487049416441111795509341260648910733163865954678717962898657490603*x^2-
130176398896181791458459621936504708298839623432402245897766115443221476925110745*x-
822702788278816708609269811910387535708844491714474156683033054021020239576593372,-x^27+639*x^24-181469*x^21+126*x^19+
30059569*x^18+374*x^17-52875*x^16-3200520314*x^15-131153*x^14+9241866*x^13+227140065437*x^12+18389824*x^11-861123553*x^10-
10744545334274*x^9-1288661506*x^8+45108241500*x^7+326660977116850*x^6+45126215945*x^5-1259442975385*x^4-5791804786248161*x^3-
631705457559*x^2+14642062395512*x+45627953854801104]
```